# select by id and specific column letter a-z

Tags: php, mysql

I have data like below , and I have array `(3, 4, 8)` mean id I have to get ,
is there a way I can use the array get rows by `subject` column letter a to z?

```
id | subject   
unsigned auto_increment | varchar(255)

id | subject     
3 | beck  
4 | agyness  
5 | zelta  
7 | bess
8 | green



for ($i=0; $i < count(id_array); $i++) {  
  ..
  select * from table where id = id_array[$i]  
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Can you not just do something like `select * from table where id in($id_array) order by subject`?

Comment: What is your criteria for selecting a subject? You're currently only selecting by ID.

Comment: by id and subject letter a-z

Comment: `select * from table where id IN (3,4,8) order by subject` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select all the id's in the array and order them by subject

```
$someArray = array(1,5,6,7);

"SELECT * from table where id IN (".implode(",", $someArray).") order by subject ";
```